# Limit of system of equations

Tags: calculus, limits, systems-of-equations

Consider a system of two equations with unknowns $x(\phi)$ and $y(\phi)$:
\begin{align}x(\phi)=F\bigl(\phi,y(\phi)\bigr)\\y(\phi)=G\bigl(\phi,x(\phi)\bigr)\end{align}
where $F,G$ are two arbitrary smooth functions. I want to take the limit of both unknown functions simultaneously, that is, I want to find the value of
$$\lim_{\phi\to0}\begin{pmatrix}x(\phi)\\y(\phi)\end{pmatrix}.$$
I'm a bit lost how to hand something like this. I already thought of plugging the second equation into the first to get
$$x(\phi)=F\bigl(\phi,G\bigl(\phi,x(\phi)\bigr)\bigr),$$
from there I could be theoretically possible to "extract" $x(\phi)$, but this approach is not feasible for my concrete problem. Any help is highly appreciated.

Edit: To be more precise, the system of equations I have is given by
\begin{align*}
    x(\phi)&=\frac{1}{\pi-2\phi}\int_{\phi}^{\pi-\phi}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\sqrt{\bigg(\frac{\alpha(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}\bigg)^2-\bigg(\frac{y(\phi)}{\tan(\theta)}\bigg)^2}\\
    y(\phi)&=\frac{1}{2\phi}\int_{-\phi}^{\phi}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\sqrt{\bigg(\frac{\alpha(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}\bigg)^2-(x(\phi)\tan(\theta))^2}
\end{align*}

Comment: Do both limits exist separately? Could any of these functions be non-zero in a neighborhood close to $0$?

Comment: The limit is not a quotient?

Comment: @WeierstraßRamirez I don't think so, one goes to infinity if you just let $\phi\to0$ and the only chance for it to be finite is when the second equation somehow counteracts this

Comment: I wonder if you can find conditions for studying the quotient.

Comment: Could you elaborate? What do you mean with studying the quotient?